# Why does the returned DataTable has readonly columns in FileHelpers

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am wondering why [filehelpers](http://filehelpers.com/runtime_classes.html) return readonly columns.

I had a huge problem with [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219717/why-does-the-value-not-get-updated-in-my-datatable-row)  not updating values and could not figure out why. Now I have to have another loop to go through all the columns and change them to be not readonly.

Is there a way I can tell Filehelpers to not do this? So I don't have to waste time going through all of it again?

Comment: `datatable.column[0].readonly = false` fixes the problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FileHelpers class `RecordOperations.CreateEmptyDataTable()` method is responsible for this and it is not virtual.

I think the reason might be that it is similar to using a normal `DataReader` via `DataTable.Load(IReader)` which would also create readonly rows.

However, it is easy to fix by going through the columns instead of the rows:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
    col.ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: Ya I know I can go through them all and make them non readonly but was wondering if there was an option or something that would save me from having to iterate over them just to do this.